# Office365: Implementing Support Desk procedures

Tags: office-365

All,

My question is both a procedural and a technical one.  I'm looking for both hard advise and practical experience on how companies have catered for setting up internal first line resource on Office 365.

SharePoint "On-Premise" used to have policies that could be set in central administration, which allowed anyone in the address book to have full read only access to SharePoint content.  In light of such policies not being present in Office365, I'm curious as to how other companies may have tackled this scenario.

Thanks
Steven

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 groups which you can leverage inside a SharePoint group, they are `Everyone` and `Everyone except external users`.

Everyone is everyone in your tenant, including external users. Everyone except external users is everyone in your tenant that is not an external user.

If you place one of these groups into a read only SharePoint group, then they will have read only access.

Also note that in the Office 365 admin portal (Gear icon -> Organizational profile), you can set up custom help information, adding a phone number, email address, and a URL for your support desk. This then shows this info in the ? pane on all sites.

As fo your initial question, we are about to launch an internal KB-esque portal with info on best practices, help, and training information. We will be leveraging one of hte 2 groups above to give everyone access.